# How to find easy questions to answer?

Tags: discussion

I'm only mildly experienced with HTML and Java, but would love to help beginner users who have more trivial, 101 type questions. But when I search through the html and java tags, it's all about PHP and Javascript, or APIs I've never touched. How do I find some lower-level questions, so I can help up new users more? I really want to help out this community.

Comment: Looking up _"Easy to answer questions"_ might be jumping on a _wrecked train_ anyways. They'll have a corresponding duplicate already, or are simply lacking research efforts, deserving them to be closed.

Comment: If you want easy questions, you'll need to play [this game](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Be ready for all the competition you're gonna get. Because who doesn't want low-hanging fruit?

Comment: You'll probably have to find some tags that are less popular in order to find easy, unanswered questions. Java and HTML get a lot of traffic, so most of the easy questions were answered long ago, and lots of people pounce on the new ones. Try to find some sub-tag for a library or framework you're familiar with, or maybe learn a new programming language and ask/answer questions in a newer tag.

Comment: Looking at questions from (pardon the expression) the bottom up can actually be an advantage. If you find a simple question answered with long quotes from the W3C pages, you may be able to provide a 'simple' answer.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks for the advice! I'll definitely look into this.