# Tag noob questions to facilitate helping out

Tags: feature-request

Similar to [How to find easy questions to answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298167/how-to-find-easy-questions-to-answer) but taken from another angle:

In relation to [Fish-out pure-java questions to help out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336663/fish-out-pure-java-questions-to-help-out):

**how about having some sort of "noob-question" tag, so that someone can help with e.g. noob java questions?**

I tried finding suitable java questions to answer, via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered, but they often require some other technology expertise, e.g. Spring or Hibernate and they are pretty obscure/arcane.

It seems hard to fish out pure-java and/or noob questions...

EDIT: Please note, that the question which was marked as duplicate is about being a new user. Whereas I don't consider myself a new user (nor a noob myself). I just have a free moment and would like to answer some noob questions...

Comment: I'd also say, through answering questions, you can learn a lot.  Perhaps you should take a plunge into learning some of these more advanced tools?  Not *every* question comes from a beginner; most askers would be using a library of some kind.

Comment: Please note, that the question which was marked as duplicate is about being a new user. Whereas I don't consider myself a new user. I just have a free moment and would like to answer some noob questions...

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how the advice differs.  There's little you can really do besides keep an eye on the Java tag and answer the questions that you feel reasonably capable of answering; however, if they're *really* that easy...they may either have five upvoted answers by then or be closed as a duplicate.  Be wary of that.

Comment: Please also note that this is more of a feature-request - asking if such noob tag could be added to StackOverflow

Comment: (neither do I consider myself a noob)

Comment: [It's been discussed at length](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36876/175248) beforehand; the main takeaway with it is that no new tags should be created (since who curates *that*?), and if you're not capable of answering a question, the best thing to do is to **not** answer the question.  Only answer ones you feel comfortable with answering.

Comment: is there a difference between a *noob* question and a *"i can't be f'ed to even google the question i just asked. do it for me"* question?

Comment: @Memor-X some things cannot be googled but require someone to look at it.

Comment: @Memor-X : certain things *can* be googled, but the results are buried within 100s of unrelated results, due to e.g. bad luck with keywords. And shouldn't StackOverflow help people save time (after the person exerting some effort on their own) ?

Comment: @KarolDepka thing that can't be googled i normally expect to be the more complex kind of things that  if your asking about you wouldn't really be a *noob* since you understand enough of the basics to be able to understand the answers. as for bad luck with keywords when i think of *noobish* question that could come from that i just can't think of a google query that could fail for a very basic question

Comment: also, just to note your search link seems to redirect to an incorrect search.  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered` becomes `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?filter=need-answers&sort=votes` which the first post i'm seeing is a bountied question with an accepted answer and the bounty isn't looking for new answers

Comment: @Memor-X : for me, the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered returns questions which have 0 answers . That url was suggested on my profile page to improve my rep on the java tag.

Comment: @Memor-X pretty sure that us due to the new navigation. The URL in the question doesn't exist in the new nav, so it redirects to a different one. Seems like it might be a bug or an oversight since the redirected destination is barely related. (Might not be a bug too, could just be a dedault redirect

Comment: @Memor-X things are hard too google happen to me on a 1-10% basis. Can't think of a good example now, though. Sometimes the results just turn out irrelevant. Sometimes a keyword is so ambiguous and it's time consuming to try to do the acrobatics and find different and different keywords just to circumvent the irrelevant results.

Comment: @Memor-X : ok, here is an example of a thing hard to google: things involving special characters, e.g. operators, e.g. in perl (which has a lot of fancy operators, whose name in english you might not know). How would you search for special characters in google?

Comment: @KarolDepka you have a point there, what i normally do i search by the actual name of the symbol like & = ampersand symbol, @ = at symbol

Comment: @Memor-X : thanks. And how often do you find the thing? I sometimes do, sometimes don't. And sometimes get really ridiculous results ;).

Answer (score 7):

## No.

Not only tags like [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner) or [newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newbie) are "meta tags" that are [considered inappropriate on Stack Overflow since 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) but also some users <strike>might</strike> will tag questions which they deem simple with them, thus making this [already unwelcoming-to-new-users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) site a lot more unwelcoming, to the point of violating [the #1 principle of any Stack Exchange site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) (emphasis added):

> Whether you've come to ask questions, or to generously share what you know, remember that we’re all here to learn, together. **Be welcoming and patient, *especially* with those who may not know everything you do.** Oh, and bring your sense of humor. Just in case.

---

> I tried finding suitable java questions to answer, via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered, but they often require some other technology expertise, e.g. Spring or Hibernate and they are pretty obscure/arcane.

Most of these "other technologies" have their own tags, which you can add to your ignored tags list. For instance, you can filter out Spring questions from your homepage by simply adding [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) to the ignored tags.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: I have added another tag (in this case - `Android`) which I'm proficient with, which grew the percentage of answerable-by-me questions  dramatically.

The url looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+android