# Fish-out pure-java questions to help out

Tags: discussion, support

Related to [Tag noob questions to facilitate helping out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336662/tag-noob-questions-to-facilitate-helping-out) but more of a support question than feature-request.

What would be the best way to fish out pure-Java questions, that do not require arcane knowledge of other technologies?

EDIT: here I don't only mean noob questions. Can be something very arcane but pure-java-specific (I'm fine answering that).

Comment: good luck, you'll find only duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

There really isn't a good way to do this.  The reasons for this are numerous...

- Not every question on Stack Overflow comes from beginners.  Many people ask who have been in the industry or are at least working with industry-grade software and equipment.
- Many questions come about from frameworks and libraries which are common to the language being specified; notably, with Java, you'll commonly run into Spring, Hibernate, and Guava.  Learning these frameworks will give you a leg up *anyway*, and will enable you to answer questions faster with them.

  To be fair, I don't expect anyone to spend a fortnight playing around with Spring Boot just for fun.  You'd want to do that to really *learn* it.
- You should really consider this a learning opportunity and expand your horizon on what libraries and technologies are out there.  As I said before, it's unrealistic to expect one to learn Spring Boot, but at least tinkering with it would be the best thing for your professional development.

One last point I'd like to make here is, if you can't answer a question because you don't know, then there's no shame in not answering it.  It's far better to ignore a question which you have no answer to than to give an incomplete or completely wrong answer and have that punish you later on.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: I have added another tag to the filter (in this case - Android) which I'm proficient with, which grew the percentage of answerable-by-me questions dramatically.

The url looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+android